# How to enable hardware acceleration for Unity on Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: unity, ati, bug-reporting, hardware-acceleration

Hardware Acceleration is disabled by default on my fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.1. I did a

```
$/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

in the terminal and got the result the everything is supported except Unity 3D. Previously I tried using 14.10 and everything was silky smooth on my machine. I am assuming that the hardware acceleration was enabled, so this shows that it is possble to run Unity with hardware acceleration. Could someone please tell me how to enable this.

My terminal output:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 10.1.3

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

I have a Lenovo G50-45 which has an A6-6310 APU, with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics.

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Is this in a VM?

Comment: No it is not a VM, it is fresh install on my Lenovo G50-45. I am using the integrated default gpu that comes with the APU.
"AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics × 4" from my about Ubuntu.

Comment: I switched to fglrx-update proprietary driver in Additional Drivers and everything is working perfectly. Steam Games are running at very good speed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install additional drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the hardware acceleration by switching to proprietary AMD driver.

This can be done by opening the "Additional Drivers" and selecting "Using video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary)".

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're running in a VM.
**OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc**
I dont think VMs have enough access to the host GPU to really utilize it effectively.

Comment: No it is not a VM.